# Issue after using Opengraph.config file

Tags: sxa

After testing the code to use the opengraph class from this article.

https://www.maartenwillebrands.nl/2021/10/05/sitecore-sxa-creating-a-proper-fallback-for-the-ogtitle-element/

I decided to remove the config and class code, I started getting this issue.

> Could not load type
> 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Services.IPassthroughService'
> from assembly 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions,
> Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I found that I have `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions` dll but did not delete any dll when removing my extended class and config. I am lost why this issue has started showing up. I want to resolve this without a full new installation of Sitecore 10.2.

Comment: That looks like wrong version of the dll. Compare it with the one from clean Sitecore setup. Most probably you referenced wrong nuget package version while developing your code.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, I fixed this by getting a clean version Sitecore binaries and this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.dll` in `bin` folder with `Version=8.0.0.0` will fix the issue.

You can also download Version `8.0.0.0` from Graphical setup package for XP Single [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/101/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_101.aspx) and copy to your local instance without reinstalling Sitecore.

1. Download the `Graphical setup package for XP Single`
2. Extract `Sitecore 10.1.0 rev. 005207 (Setup XP0 Developer Workstation rev. 1.2.2-r1).zip`
3. Find and Extract `Sitecore Experience Accelerator 10.1.0.3751.scwdp.zip
4. Go to `Sitecore Experience Accelerator 10.1.0.3751.scwdp\Content\Website\bin`
5. Copy `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.dll` and place it into your local bin folder.

   [image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of a version mismatch between the `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.dll` that is deployed to the website, and the one that Sitecore is looking for. This can happen due to a variety of things, but I suspect you have a different version of `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.dll` in your code, and when you're publishing the site, the correct DLL is getting overwritten with the version referenced by the code. Make sure that the one you're referencing in your code matches the version of Sitecore that you're using.

So download the correct version of the `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions` from `nuget` package manager as per your Sitecore version in the visual studio like this.

[image]

If you don't want to add this to your project, then you can create a test application, and using the nuget package manager you can download the DLL and deploy that one to your Sitecore site.

Hope this will solve your issue.